# Why can't I edit my values with my UI slider in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript, uislider

I made a UI slider that moves according to a value in my script(playtime) and it runs smoothly so far. here's my slider code

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class testingtime : MonoBehaviour {

    public int playtime =0;
    public int seconds = 0;
    private int minutes = 0;
    private int hours = 0;
    public int playtimemax = 0;

    public Slider testslider;
    public Texture playbutton;
    public Texture Pausebutton;

     Texture substitute;
    bool ispaused = false;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        substitute = Pausebutton;
        StartCoroutine ("playtimer");
    }

    private IEnumerator playtimer(){
        while (true) {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
            playtime += 1;
            seconds = (playtime % 60);
            minutes = (playtime / 60) % 60;
            hours = (playtime / 3600) % 24;

                }
        }



    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        testslider.value = playtime;

        if (ispaused) {
            Time.timeScale = 0;
            substitute = playbutton;
                }
        if (!ispaused) {
            Time.timeScale = 1;
            substitute = Pausebutton;
                }
        playtime = (int)testslider.value;

    }
    void  OnGUI (){
    if (GUI.Button (new Rect (685,710, 20, 20), substitute)) {
            ispaused = !ispaused;
        }

        GUI.Label (new Rect (50, 50, 400, 50), "Playtime = " + hours.ToString () + " Hours " + minutes.ToString () + " Minutes " + seconds.ToString () + " Seconds");

        }
}
```

So basically this makes my slider move according to playtime which increases by 1 every second like a timer.
However I tried to change the value of playtime through the slider (I have interactable enabled) with the code `playtime = (int)testslider.value;`.
I am aware that i cannot move the slider because it keeps updating `testtimer.value = playtime`.
Is there any function available, something like testtimer.onclicked, so that I can put it in a if function and disable the updating?

Answer (score 1):

Slider has [`onValueChanged`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Slider-onValueChanged.html) callback, which you can use for that purpose.

Comment: How is it supposed to be used?

Comment: Also if my slider.value = playtimer and is updating every second wouldnt it trigger the onvaluechanged method as well

Comment: The documentation includes an example.

Answer (score 1):

I got it guys! :D FINALLY
All you need is this code

```
public void adjusttimer(float newtime){
        playtime = (int)newtime;
        }
```

and assign the method like so[image]

it should work just perfectly. :D
Much thanks to Max Yankov for the idea!

Comment: I'd prefer to subscribe to it in code, though — if you're relying on that subscription for code to be correct, it's more fragile to do it in the editor.